# relation of substantive/verb to declarative/procedural memory

Tags: cognitive-modeling, brain-development, linguistics

Is there a relation between "declarative vs. procedural memory" and "substantive vs. verb"?
For example, are substantives (as a kind of information entities) stored in the declarative memory whereas verbs define capabilities/behavior and hence stored in the procedural memory?

Example:

Tree: a substantive, can directly be stored in declarative memory

to climb: a verb, defines a capability/behavior and can be stored in the procedural memory

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that universal nouns will link mostly to other universal nouns (*a tree is a plant*), and universal verbs will link mostly to other universal verbs (*to climb is to move*), it is not necessary that they be in separate memory areas from each other; or even that they be separate from event memory (*one cat did climb one tree*).  The most efficient memory scheme would minimize the length of all links.  One way would be to store all new memories in a fairly linear structure, and then use an off-line process (sleep) to spread them around to minimize total link lengths {or to optimize lengths around importance of fast access}.